# how to save input from form2 into datagrid in form1?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, datagrid

i've had some issues with the following database and datagrid updates tryouts in vb2013.
I have a datagrid and a "Create New Profile" Button(btnnewprofile) on Form1(uebersicht), the button opens Form2(neuesprofil) as a ShowDialog().

How do i get the input from Form2 showed in the datagrid in Form1?

Here the Code for Form1

```
Public Class uebersicht


Private Sub TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    '  Me.Validate()
    '  Me.TableBindingSource.EndEdit()
    '   Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1DataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub uebersicht_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: Diese Codezeile lädt Daten in die Tabelle "Database1DataSet.Table". Sie können sie bei Bedarf verschieben oder entfernen.
    '     Me.TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Table)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnnewprofile.Click


    neuesprofil.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Public Sub TableDataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles TableDataGridViewuebersicht.CellContentClick

End Sub
```

End Class

Code for Form 2

```
    Public Class neuesprofil


Public Sub TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click


End Sub

'  Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'TODO: Diese Codezeile lädt Daten in die Tabelle "Database1DataSet.Table". Sie können sie bei Bedarf verschieben oder entfernen.
'  Me.TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Table)

' End Sub



Public Sub btnsvprfl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsvprfl.Click

    uebersicht.TableBindingSource.AddNew()

    Try



        Me.Validate()

        Me.TableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Database1DataSet)
        MsgBox("Profil wurde gespeichert!")




        Me.Hide()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

As you can see, i've messed around with some comment lines and private/public declarations,
hoping to solve this issue. When accepting the input on form2, the datagrid creates a new line, but without information stored within. How can i get it to work?

Comment: English comments would help even more in the understanding. ;)

Comment: One way to access data from one form to another form would be to create a public object (say with name m_object) and access it the code however. Like "Dim x as string = Form1Name.m_object.tostring()". Also, you have it opened as "ShowDialog" which will block all GUI threads. You might want to do just ".Show()".

Comment: Raise an event on form2 that will refresh form1 or whatever you want to do

Comment: @Gàbor, these comments are auto generated, nothing interesting to see there

Comment: @Codexer, I've just build a refresh onto the "Save Profile" button, had one before on Form1 for controlling the inputs - the refreshing on both Forms just removes the new row that was generated on startup of Form2

Comment: @sparkysword so do I have to declare every textbox input as a string? I have about 15 textboxes on form2 also a image that should be saved into the database

Comment: As you see above - there are 10 different ways of doing it - public object, event, direct form access, pass of object, save to db - get from db, etc. So, you either push it to parent form or ping the parent form to get data somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
If Form1.DataGridView1.RowCount <> 0 Then
        Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Selected = True
        Dim valueOfFirstRowFirstColumn As String = Form1.DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value
        MsgBox(valueOfFirstRowFirstColumn)
End If
```

Hope this helps